# PCB potting with Lithium battery

Tags: pcb, potting

I'm designing an electronics prototype for a college project that will be buried in the soil in the middle of a field. So power is basically not available. I am adding a solar panel and want to integrate the controller as well as a lithium battery inside the enclosure. Since it will be in the field, I am thinking of potting the enclosure to prevent water inside the enclosure. Basically, I googled and duck duck goed lithium battery safe PCB potting compound and I found nothing. So I would really appreciate if someone could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly which Lithium battery are you intending to use?

Comment: Are you sure it's a Lithium battery (not rechargeable)? Or is it a Li-ion battery (rechargeable)?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of Duck-Duck , I was thinking of Tuck Tape, which has a great seal but I don't know about slow diffusion.

Then I found this.

https://www.duckbrand.com/products/paint-diy-tapes/hvac-tapes/silver-188-in-x-10-yd-1

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Tape won't work to seal the enclosure we are using.

Comment: be aware of thermal implications and  you need a teflon plug to leak H2

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a recommendation for a material choice to use as potting compound ???

Burying it in neutral RTV would work great. It'd be waterproof until the apocalypse comes around. There's a million places to get such RTV, but here's a description so you get it right. The key word is "Neutral". Many RTV's outgas nasty stuff, you don't want those.

https://cht-silicones.com/products/adhesives/neutral-cure-rtvs-adhesives

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question.

Comment: Well, then, do the right thing and mark this comment as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search revealed the following [results](https://www.epicresins.com/Batteries/LithiumIon),
that company and [many others](https://nz.element14.com/c/chemicals-adhesives/potting-compounds?potting-compound-type=pur-polyurethane-) offer polyurethane potting compounds, and it seems to be a [very common practice](https://www.masterbond.com/industrial-applications/potting-and-encapsulation-compounds-batteries).